# My dynamic imageview cannot display image from the url it gets using json

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
        public void addAttendance(ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            //tl.removeView(tr);
            tl.removeAllViews();
            //addHeaderAttendance();
            ctr=0;
            for (Iterator i = attendanceusers.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

                Properties p = (Properties) i.next();

                property_list.add(p);
                /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
                tr = new TableRow(this);
                //
              //  attendanceid=p.getAttendID();
                remarks=p.getStudRemark(); //get remark
                //
             /**declaration of layout**/ 
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
            Ll.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            profile = new ImageView(this);
            URL newurl = new URL(p.getPic()); 
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream()); 
            if (bmp != null){
            profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);}
            profile.setPadding(0,50,0,0);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
            Ll.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            Ll.addView(profile,params);

            tr.addView((View)Ll);
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

My `imageview` profile doesn't display the url it gets. I am debugging the code and i saw that it is getting the url but is not displaying the image. I am debugging my code when i hover newurl i am seeing the url of the image and then when i press `f6` it goes to the

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

and when i hover the newurl inside the ipen parenthesis i am seeing also the url of the image, but when i press f6 again it goes back to the start, it doesn't pass through:

```
 profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: use **`Glide`** or **`Picasso`** to load image from url

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso to show image in the imageView using URL

Comment: that code works if im not adding it dynamically but when it is dynamic it is not working

Comment: update your error log.